# for in loop returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I want to look through an object but I am not sure what it actually contains, and when I loop as follows I get the following results:

```
<% for(var index in errors) {%>
    <%= errors[index] %>
<% } %>

[object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object]
```

I DO expect to get back 5 results, but I need to somehow delve deeper into the loop and get the actual content of the objects inside, but I do not know how to do that?

This is all plain javascript, the script above is just a templating engine for node/express.

Comment: probably there in another object in `errors`.add `JSON.stringify`

Comment: JSON.stringify(errors[index]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stringify` your objects before printing:

```
<% for(var index in errors) {%>
    <%= JSON.stringify(errors[index]) %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: that's getting it there! just one more issue, when I stringify I get literal JSON objects, param:msg, and so I did `JSON.stringify(errors[index].msg)` and I do get the appropriate messages BUT surrounded in quiotes such as: `"Name field is required"`. Any idea how to get rid of the quotes?

Comment: You need stringify only when you want to print objects. `msg` is a string so you can skip stringify: `<%= errors[index].msg %>`.

Answer (score 0):

The error object might be like,
`error={`
 `{},{},{}`
   `}`

The format **<%= %>**, only prints the string value not the object literals,
If you want to debug, you can write **JSON.stringify(errors[index])**.

Or if you want to print the child elements use **error[index]['childKeyName']**